# Java UnmarshalException on shutdown / System.exit from MBean via JConsole

Tags: java, jmx, shutdown, unmarshalling, jconsole

I'm wondering how to avoid getting this exception when I use an MBean with JConsole to remotely execute a shutdown, which calls `System.exit(1)`.  I've verified I get no exception when shutdown is not called so everything else is set up right.  Error is:

`Problem invoking shutdown: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException`

Which certainly makes sense!  I just don't want this to be an error condition.

Comment: Did you marshalling that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected.  I assume that your JMX operation is what initiated the `System.exit(1)`?  It means that Jconsole was waiting for a response from the server and none was sent before the socket was closed.  Even calling a `void` method via JMX waits for an acknowledgement so jconsole can say "Method successfully invoked".  Since the server is shutting down, it makes sense that you don't get a response.

If you want to avoid this you can fork a thread to sleep a bit and then issue the exit.  Something like:

```
 public String jmxShutdown() {
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignored
             }
             System.exit(1);
         }
     });
     return "Shutting down";
 }
```

Comment: That's correct @djechlin.   Even a void method waits for an acknowledgement so jconsole can say "Method successfully invoked".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, it could also be worth to [configure your own `JMXConnectorServer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23273580/1523648) and stop the connector server from the JMX method instead of calling `System.exit()`. A manually configured connector server is running in a user thread, so when the server is stopped (and there are no other user threads running), the JVM will also terminate.

The advantage of this approach is that the connector server ensures that all running JMX calls are still processed normally before releasing its user thread. I've verified this behaviour by creating a test MBean method that calls [`stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorServerMBean.html#stop%28%29) on the connector server and sleeps for a second afterwards, and I always got a response when calling the test method from a JMX client.

Comment: I think the OP _wants_ to shutdown the application with `System.exit(...)`.

Comment: Nevertheless, a different solution may be useful for others having the slightly more general question "How to shut down a process via JMX and still receive the JMX response". I'm not only answering this question for the OP.