# Start JMX from webapp tomee

Tags: java, jmx, apache-tomee

Instead of running the application from the beginning with JMX for tomee as CATALINA_OPTS.

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=password.properties \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=access.properties \
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore \
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password \
```

I want to enable JMX from my app after the code startup.
as the time will log the passwords to log file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the JMXConnectorServer of the platform MBeanServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273579/how-to-get-the-jmxconnectorserver-of-the-platform-mbeanserver)

Comment: I found a way to prevent logging of the Catalina opts into the console.

Comment: You can put the properties into `catalina.properties` or add set `logArgs="false"` on the `VersionLoggerListener`.

Comment: Yes i did the same